# java JNLP error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp, http-proxy

I'm trying to run a java **JNLP**-based application.
It works fine from home : javac+javaws are the same v.1.8.?

Now I'm trying to run my application at work. I'm working behind a **proxy** and I used the Controlpanel to tell java to bypass the proxy for our local server hosting the JNLP.
On the server side, the aplication is compiled with

```
javac 1.7.0_60
```

On the client side, I'm trying to run it with:

```
$ javaws -version
Java(TM) Web Start 11.40.2.26-fcs 

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
```

Nevertheless, I get the following exception in javaws

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:969)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:904)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1432)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1429)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.doRevocationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.doRevocationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.checkRevocationStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509TrustManagerDelegate.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1460)
    ... 33 more
```

I read https://community.oracle.com/thread/3651870?start=15&tstart=0
But I don't really understand what I should do.

For example, I've commented out <>/lib/security/java.security

```
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

but that still doesn't work. As I see a '**getInputStream**' in the stacktrace, I wonder if javaws tries to download something outside the proxy ?

Any idea ?

**EDIT**: the JNLP works if,in the controlPanel, I check

- Perform signed code: do not check (not recommended)
- Perform TLS certificatie revocation: do not check (not recommended)

is this problem linked to my proxy server ?

Answer (score 1):

[Java certificate revocation checking](https://java.com/en/download/help/revocation_options.xml) uses one or both of these methods:

> #### Certificate Revocations Lists (CRLs)
>
> This method needs lists to be generated and published periodically by Certificate Authority (CA) to keep the it current.
>
> #### Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)
>
> This method performs a real time certificate status check with CA making it more reliable and faster.

If your server certificate is self-signed, or your company has an internal CA, your JRE may not be able to complete the revocation check properly -- hence the "Unknown" status. If you want to run with revocation checking on (and usually you do), you will need certs signed by a CA that supports one or both of these methods.

It is also important to remember that there are potentially two certificates in play here:

- The cert used to sign the JARs; and
- The cert used to connect to the server

Both certs must be signed and valid (that is, not revoked) in order for the handshake to succeed.